# Why is my SVG icon not centered?

Tags: css, svg

http://jsfiddle.net/VJ3uN/

I have an SVG icon in a parent box.  As soon as I start adding padding to the parent, the SVG icon is snapping to near the bottom of the box.  Any ideas why?

relevant html:

```
<div class="icon">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 32 32" height="100%" width="100%">
        <path id="gear" fill-rule="evenodd" d="..."></path>
    </svg>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.icon {
    width   : 16px;
    height  : 16px;
    padding : 40px;
    border  : 1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let your browser handle `width` and `height` automatically by delete `width` and `height` in `<svg>` element.

```
<div class="icon">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 32 32">
        <path id="gear" fill-rule="evenodd" d="..."></path>
    </svg>
</div>
```

If it not working, according to this bug https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=82489) please put this selector to your stylesheet

```
svg {
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Here is a result: http://jsfiddle.net/gGfx5/3/

Comment: Seem like Chrome dev fixed this issue. I edited the answer for latest Chrome stable version.

Answer (score -1):

Using CSS to vertically centre elements inside a container has always involved some sort of hack, such as setting the parent's display property to table-cell:

```
.parentContainer {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Here's your fiddle again, successfully using this technique: http://jsfiddle.net/D87Vy/. Note that this has nothing to do with the fact that the child is an SVG.

If supporting older browsers is not an issue for you, you can use the modern (and non-hacky) CSS3 flexbox module, which allows you to achieve just about any arrangement of children within a parent. Of the popular browsers, it's mostly IE7 - 10 that have partial or no support for flexbox. The fiddle above demonstrates how to center a child by adding the following to the parent:

```
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
```

Here's a guide to flexbox: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I'm not actually vertically centering anything, I'm adding padding to a very small element, the element shouldn't be being resized because of it.  And I can't use flexbox.  The issue actually is around the fact that it's SVG (at least in Chrome/Safari).

Comment: Ah, I assumed you were trying to vertically center. Could you clarify what you're trying to achieve?